# SwiftUI creates destination views before the user navigates to them

Tags: ios, list, networking, swiftui, navigationview

I am having a hard time creating in SwiftUI a pretty common use case in UIKit.

Here is the scenario. Let's suppose we want to create a master/detail app in which the user can select an item from a list and navigate to a screen with more details.

To get out of the common `List` examples from Apple's tutorial and WWDC video, the app needs to fetch the data for each screen from a REST API.

The problem: the declarative syntax of SwiftUI leads to the creation of all the destination views as soon as the rows in the `List` appear.

Here is an example using the Stack Overflow API. The list in the first screen will show a list of questions. Selecting a row will lead to a second screen that shows the body of the selected question. The full Xcode project is [on GitHub](https://github.com/matteom/NetworkedList))

First of all, we need a structure representing a question.

```
struct Question: Decodable, Hashable {
    let questionId: Int
    let title: String
    let body: String?
}

struct Wrapper: Decodable {
    let items: [Question]
}
```

(The `Wrapper` structure is needed because the Stack Exchange API wraps results in a JSON object)

Then, we create a `BindableObject` for the first screen, which fetches the list of questions from the REST API.

```
class QuestionsData: BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<QuestionsData, Never>()

    var questions: [Question] = [] {
        didSet { didChange.send(self) }
    }

    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow")!
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: .main)
        session.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let wrapper = try! decoder.decode(Wrapper.self, from: data!)
            self?.questions = wrapper.items
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Similarly, we create a second `BindableObject` for the detail screen, which fetches the body of the selected question (pardon the repetition of the networking code for the sake of simplicity).

```
class DetaildData: BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<DetaildData, Never>()

    var question: Question {
        didSet { didChange.send(self) }
    }

    init(question: Question) {
        self.question = question
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/\(question.questionId)?site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Z(-wwYGT")!
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: .main)
        session.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let wrapper = try! decoder.decode(Wrapper.self, from: data!)
            self?.question = wrapper.items[0]
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

The two SwiftUI views are straightforward.

- The first one contains a `List` inside of a `NavigationView`. Each
  row is contained in a `NavigationButton` that leads to the detail
  screen.
- The second view simply displays the body of a question in a multiline
  `Text` view.

Each view has an `@ObjectBinding` to the respective object created above.

```
struct QuestionListView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var data: QuestionsData

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data.questions.identified(by: \.self)) { question in
                NavigationButton(destination: DetailView(data: DetaildData(question: question))) {
                    Text(question.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObjectBinding var data: DetaildData

    var body: some View {
        data.question.body.map {
            Text($0).lineLimit(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

If you run the app, it works.

The problem though is that each `NavigationButton` wants a destination view. Given the declarative nature of SwiftUI, when the list is populated, a `DetailView` is immediately created for each row.

One might argue that SwiftUI views are lightweight structures, so this is not an issue. The problem is that each of these views needs a `DetaildData` instance, which immediately starts a network request upon creation, before the user taps on a row. You can put a breakpoint or a `print` statement in its initializer to verify this.

It is possible, of course, to delay the network request in the `DetaildData` class by extracting the networking code into a separate method, which we then call using `onAppear(perform:)` (which you can see in the final code on GitHub).

But this still leads to the creation of multiple instances of `DetaildData`, which are never used, and are a waste of memory. Moreover, in this simple example, these objects are lightweight, but in other scenarios they might be expensive to build.

Is this how SwiftUI is supposed to work? or am I missing some critical concept?

Comment: I think it is a bug https://twitter.com/chriseidhof/status/1144242544680849410, the tweet also mentions a workaround for time https://gist.github.com/chriseidhof/d2fcafb53843df343fe07f3c0dac41d5

Comment: It seems that SwiftUI encourages a 2-step view creation by design, with lightweight initialisation, just as you did in your example. This is similar in concept to the prefetching APIs in UITableView and UICollectionView, so it could be actually desirable.

Answer (score 6):

As you have discovered, a `List` (or a `ForEach`) creates the row view for each of its rows when the `List` is asked for its body. Concretely, in this code:

> ```
> struct QuestionListView : View {
>     @ObjectBinding var data: QuestionsData
>
>     var body: some View {
>         NavigationView {
>             List(data.questions.identified(by: \.self)) { question in
>                 NavigationButton(destination: DetailView(data: DetailData(question: question))) {
>                     Text(question.title)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

When SwiftUI asks `QuestionListView` for its `body`, the `QuestionListView` `body` accessor will immediately create one `DetailView` and one `DetailData` for every `Question` in `data.questions`.

**However**, SwiftUI does **not** ask a `DetailView` for its `body` until the `DetailView` is on the screen. So if your `List` has room for 12 rows on screen, SwiftUI will only ask the first 12 `DetailView`s for their `body` properties.

So, don't kick off the `dataTask` in `DetailData`'s `init`. Kick it off lazily in `DetailData`'s `question` accessor. That way, it won't run until SwiftUI asks the `DetailView` for its `body`.

Comment: I guess this is not a bug, it's by design to behave like this, I believe that you have to make the View to be as lightweight as possible

Comment: I think it's not a bug, but I also think they might improve it later. `List` and `ForEach` both require `Data` to conform to `RandomAccessCollection`, and both take the `rowContent` closure as `@escaping`. This leaves room for them to be changed to only request row content views for visible rows on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Please see MwcsMac's accepted answer for a really clean solution to this:

[SwiftUI NavigationLink loads destination view immediately, without clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594159/swiftui-navigationlink-loads-destination-view-immediately-without-clicking)

**Edit**: This is very helpful if you simply have lots of destination views (like a list of options, all wrapped with NavigationLink). For those situations where actual code is being executed (like the original network fetch example, above) then refactoring to use a more correct lazy loading strategy would be far more effective.

Comment: Thanks, but I would say that is a workaround to use an old mental model similar to the one we had for UIKit.

I wrote this question shortly after SwiftUI was released and that was my mental model too. After using the framework for a long time, I came to the conclusion that this behavior is as expected. What we did in initializers in UIKit view controllers should not be translated to SwiftUI views and should be moved somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. After working with (or should I say trying to work with) SwiftUI for several months now, I'm giving up and re-writing my whole app with UIKit instead. SwiftUI is just wrong, and the god-awful mashup of Combine and SwiftUI with the utterly dreadful documentation is just too much. I wish I'd never heard of it now. I need performance, and SwiftUI doesn't cut it.