# A generics problem whilst creating a lazy NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, navigation, lazy-loading

I noticed that when using `NavigationLink`s in SwiftUI, the destination views are loaded before they are presented, which causes an issue in my application.

I used the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234030/831225) to solve this problem creating a NavigationLazyView as follows:

```
struct NavigationLazyView<Content: View>: View {
    let build: () -> Content
    init(_ build: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.build = build
    }
    var body: Content {
        build()
    }
}
```

and I use it like this in my views:

```
struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: NavigationLazyView(ViewB())){
            Text(text: "Click me")
        }  
    }
}
```

I tried to go a step further, and create a lazy version of a navigation link:

```
struct NavigationLazyLink<Content1 : View, Content2 : View> : View {
   
    let destination : () -> Content1;
    let viewBuilder : () -> Content2;
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: NavigationLazyView(destination())){
            viewBuilder()
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to use `NavigationLazyLink` like this:

```
struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLazyLink(destination: ViewB()){
            Text(text: "Click me")
        }  
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

- `Cannot convert value of type 'ViewB' to expected argument type '() -> Content1'`
- `Generic parameter 'Content1' could not be inferred`
- `Explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue`

**I can't quite get by head around the problem and I have a feeling I have misunderstood how to use generic types**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `destination` is a closure:

```
let destination : () -> Content1
```

So you need to pass `ViewB` as a closure:

```
NavigationLazyLink(destination: { ViewB() }) {
    Text("Click me")
}
```

Comment: Using this solution I am getting 'Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'' on the NavigationLazyLink when trying to initialise it.