# Strange issue of "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior"

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Goal: have a SwiftUI architecture where the "add new item" and "edit existing item" are solved by the same view (EditItemView). However, for some reason, when I do this, the runtime agent complains of "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior".

This is the code I want to use, which ensures that the EDITING of the item and ADDING a new item are handled by the same EditItemView:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView
    {
        
        ScrollView
        {
            LazyVGrid(columns: my_columns)
            {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id)
                {
                    let item = $0
                    
                    // THIS LINE TO EDIT AN EXISTING ITEM
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditItemView(item: item))
                    {
                        ItemView(item: item)
                    }
                    
                }

            }
            
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            // THIS LINE TO ADD A NEW ITEM:
            NavigationLink(destination: EditItemView(item: Data.singleton.createItem(name: "New item", value: 5.0))
            {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, leading to the issue highlighted above. I am forced to separate the functionality for Edit and Add into two distinct Views, which then works:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView
    {
        
        ScrollView
        {
            LazyVGrid(columns: my_columns)
            {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id)
                {
                    let item = $0
                    
                    // THIS LINE TO EDIT AN EXISTING ITEM
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditItemView(item: item))
                    {
                        ItemView(item: item)
                    }
                    
                }

            }
            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented)
        {
            // FORCED TO USE SEPARATE VIEW
            AddItemView { name, value in
                _ = Data.singleton.createItem(name: name, value: value)
                self.isPresented = false
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { self.isPresented.toggle()}) { Image(systemName: "plus")})
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the code in the first version is considered to modify the state while updating view, because to me, it's sequential: new Item is created and THEN a view is shown for that Item.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination of `NavigationLink` is *not* rendered lazily, meaning it'll get rendered when the `NavigationLink` itself is rendered -- not when clicked through.

The `sheet` code, depending on platform and SwiftUI version, may have the same issue, but apparently does not in the version you're using. Or, the closure you provide to `AddItemView` isn't run immediately -- since you didn't include the code, it's not clear.

To solve the issue in the first method, you can use the following SO answer which provides a lazy `NavigationLink`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234030/560942