# Having trouble initializing sub-view when navigating to it from parent?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to navigate to a subview and initialize it from a property passed from the parent view **WITHOUT using onAppear**.

I am able to make this work with onAppear but don't like how it calls the function everytime the view shows up and there has to be a cleaner way??

I want to initialize PopupCollectorView by calling loadCollectors in its init() function
but I keep getting errors:

"Variable 'self.profileData' used before being initialized"

"Variable 'self.profileData' used before being initialized"

"Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

How can I make the subview view call loadCollectors() with the profileData I am passing to it??

THANK YOU

**PARENT VIEW** - all inside a navigation view hierarchy...

```
struct PopupProfileFull: View {
    @ObservedObject var popupVM : PopupProfileViewModel
    
    @State var presentCollectors: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let profileData = popupVM.profileData {
                // tapping on this triggers navigation to popupCollectorsView
                PopupAccountStats(popupVM: popupVM, presentCollectors: $presentCollectors, presentCollecting: $presentCollecting)
                .background (
                    NavigationLink("", destination: PopupCollectorsView(profileData: $popupVM.profileData), isActive: $presentCollectors)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CHILD VIEW NAVIGATED TO FROM PARENT**

```
struct PopupCollectorsView: View {
    @StateObject var popupCollectorVM = PopupCollectorsViewModel()
    
    @Binding var profileData: ProfileData?
    
     // ERRORS OCCUR HERE
     init(profileData: ProfileData) {
        self.profileData = profileData
        loadCollectors()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(0..<popupCollectorVM.collectors.count, id: \.self) { i in
                Text(popupCollectorVM.collectors[i].collectedUsername)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadCollectors() {
        if let profileData = profileData {
            popupCollectorVM.loadCollectors(userId: profileData.userId)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `profileData` directly to the `loadCollectors` function:

```
struct PopupCollectorsView: View {
    @StateObject var popupCollectorVM = PopupCollectorsViewModel()
    
    @Binding var profileData: ProfileData?
    
     init(profileData: ProfileData) {
         self.profileData = profileData
         loadCollectors(data: profileData)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(0..<popupCollectorVM.collectors.count, id: \.self) { i in
                Text(popupCollectorVM.collectors[i].collectedUsername)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadCollectors(data: ProfileData) {
        popupCollectorVM.loadCollectors(userId: data.userId)
    }
}
```

You could simplify even further by getting rid of the `loadCollectors` function (however, see my note at the end about using `init` for tasks like this):

```
init(profileData: ProfileData) {
  self.profileData = profileData
  popupCollectorVM.loadCollectors(userId: profileData.userId)
}
```

You *may* (hard to tell without being able to run your example) also have to use something like [`NavigationLazyView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234030/560942) so that your `View` doesn't reach `init` before the correct data is passed to it.

It's also worth noting that generally, you want to *avoid* doing heavy lifting in `init` since SwiftUI views are transient and can be recreated often. The above solution will work if you have a high degree of confidence that you're view will only reach `init` *once*, but in general, it's better to rely on something like `onAppear` or even the `init` method of a `@StateObject` that only gets run once.